# grails command on grails 2.4.0 app throws sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: KeyUsage does not allow digital signatures

Tags: java, maven, ssl, grails, remote-repository

I was getting “PKIX path building failed” and “unable to find valid certification path to requested target” error earlier. So I downloaded the certificates from the repository site - https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/  by browsing on chrome and downloading cer format certificates for all the certificates in the chain (total 4). I then added them to the Jre cacerts path like this -

```
sudo keytool -importcert -alias forecepoint2 -file ~/Desktop/Forcepoint\ Cloud\ OPS\ CA.cer -keystore /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_80.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/security/cacerts
```

I can see the entries by exporting the same.
I am getting this error still -

Stacktrace -

```
| Error Resolve error obtaining dependencies: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-jasper:jar:7.0.53 (NOTE: Stack trace has been filtered. Use --verbose to see entire trace.)
org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-jasper:jar:7.0.53
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:335)
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.readArtifactDescriptor(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:217)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.resolveCachedArtifactDescriptor(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:537)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.getArtifactDescriptorResult(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:521)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:421)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:375)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.process(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:363)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.doRecurse(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:506)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:470)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:375)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.process(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:363)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.collectDependencies(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:266)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.collectDependencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:337)
    at grails.util.BuildSettings.doResolve(BuildSettings.groovy:514)
    at grails.util.BuildSettings.doResolve(BuildSettings.groovy)
    at grails.util.BuildSettings$_getDefaultBuildDependencies_closure19.doCall(BuildSettings.groovy:775)
    at grails.util.BuildSettings$_getDefaultBuildDependencies_closure19.doCall(BuildSettings.groovy)
    at grails.util.BuildSettings.getDefaultBuildDependencies(BuildSettings.groovy:769)
    at grails.util.BuildSettings.getBuildDependencies(BuildSettings.groovy:674)
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-jasper:pom:7.0.53 from/to repo1_maven_org_maven2 (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2): sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: KeyUsage does not allow digital signatures
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:462)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:264)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:241)
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:320)
    ... 18 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactTransferException: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-jasper:pom:7.0.53 from/to repo1_maven_org_maven2 (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2): sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: KeyUsage does not allow digital signatures
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.ArtifactTransportListener.transferFailed(ArtifactTransportListener.java:43)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$TaskRunner.run(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:355)
    at org.eclipse.aether.util.concurrency.RunnableErrorForwarder$1.run(RunnableErrorForwarder.java:67)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$DirectExecutor.execute(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:581)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector.get(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:249)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.performDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:538)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:439)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: KeyUsage does not allow digital signatures
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:436)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:180)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:294)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:643)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:479)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:906)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DecompressingHttpClient.execute(DecompressingHttpClient.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.aether.transport.http.HttpTransporter.execute(HttpTransporter.java:279)
    at org.eclipse.aether.transport.http.HttpTransporter.implGet(HttpTransporter.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.aether.spi.connector.transport.AbstractTransporter.get(AbstractTransporter.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$GetTaskRunner.runTask(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:447)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$TaskRunner.run(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:350)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: KeyUsage does not allow digital signatures
```